# GWTP using Spring in server side

Tags: spring, gwt, gwt-platform, gwtp

I am working with gwtp and I would like to use Spring on the server side. I have seen that Spring is include in gwtp, but I don't know how I can use it. Anyone can help me about that?
Will be cool some example.

I have looked for by google, but no way :(

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Well, I don´t know about gwtp, but I can assure you I have used Spring-security in the Server side. So, if you are thinking in the server side, yes, you can use Spring (all frameworks based on Java are suitable for the server).

Comment: yes, I think so. But the problem is to know how I can integrate gwtp with Spring. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

GWTP is using GIN pattern `(Dependency Injection at Client Side)` and it's default integration with GUICE at DI server side. for more detail [GWTP](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/)

Spring is server side [DI pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

```
I have seen that Spring is include in gwtp,
```

It does not include Spring at all. it's default integration with GUICE. but you can use spring with it.

- [gwtp-sample-basic-spring example](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/source/browse/gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-basic-spring/?r=6ab84e91310558334c2e8836dcabeafa03f137a3)

Answer (score 3):

Well, at first you have to configure Spring in your `web.xml` descriptor:

```
<listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/yourProjectName/springGwtServices/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Notice that you need the [Spring4GWT](http://code.google.com/p/spring4gwt/) library for this example.
Next, in your `RemoteService` interfaces you need to specify the `RemoteServiceRelativePath` like this example:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("springGwtServices/userService")
public interface UserService extends extends RemoteService{
  public User getUserByLogin(String name);  
  public void logout();
  public void deleteUserById(Long userId);
}
```

And now, you just need to implement your service as in any Spring app.
Example, suppose you want an action to delete a User by ID and using the GWTP paradigm:
In server side, here is the Handler:

```
@Repository("deleteUserHandler")
public class DeleteUserHandler extends AbstractActionHandler<DeleteUserAction, DeleteUserResult> {

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  public DeleteUserHandler(){
    super(DeleteUserAction.class);
  }

  @Override
  public DeleteUserResult execute(DeleteUserAction action, ExecutionContext arg1)
        throws ActionException {
    Long idToDel = action.getUserToDeleteId();
    if(idToDel != null){
        userService.deleteUserById(idToDel);
    }
    return new DeleteUserResult();
  }

  @Override
  public void undo(DeleteUserAction arg0, DeleteUserResult arg1,
        ExecutionContext arg2) throws ActionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

}
```

The `DeleteUserAction` is as follows

```
public class DeleteUserAction  extends UnsecuredActionImpl<DeleteUserResult> {
    private Long userToDeleteId;

    public DeleteUserAction(Long userToDel) {
    this.userToDeleteId = userToDel;
    }

    /**
     * For serialization only.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private DeleteUserAction() {
    }

    public Long getUserToDeleteId() {
        return userToDeleteId;
    }

    public void setUserToDeleteId(Long userToDeleteId) {
        this.userToDeleteId = userToDeleteId;
    }

}
```

And finally the Result class:

```
public class DeleteUserResult  implements Result {
   /**
    * For serialization only.
    */
   //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
   public DeleteUserResult() {
   }

}
```

I hope this helps.
PS: I suppose you can do the Spring things (application context etc..) by yourself, if not, please tell

Answer (score 0):

You can find some good examples on GWTP repository in Github. We recently migrated all of our from Google Code to Github, which hosts the latest version.

Remember you can also use REST communication using the new GWTP-Dispatch-Rest, with that you don't need a lot of configuration code to integrate GWTP with Spring server side.

https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP-Samples